# MYSQL - show data between 2 dates if every date counter matches the condition

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to show different plans to customers if the are available for customers by dates.
e.g if a customer choose date between 2 to 4 august and want to see the plan

my issue is while running mysql query and when there are plan sold out for 4 august query still showing results.

```
From 02-04 august

Plans available

On 02 -> 2
On 03 -> 0
```

My aim is to get 0 rows in returns when customer want to buy 1 plan between 2 to 4th august.

MySQL query:

```
SELECT bs.`sales_available` sale_to,hp.`package_name`
FROM `tbl_booking_categories` bc 
LEFT JOIN `tbl_booking_suite` bs ON bc.`id`=bs.`booking_cat_id` 
LEFT JOIN `tbl_holiday_packages` hp ON hp.`id`=bc.`package_id` 
LEFT JOIN `tbl_room_type` rt ON rt.`id`=bc.`room_type_id` 
WHERE bc.`room_type_id`='5' AND  bs.booked_date IN ('2017-08-10','2017-08-11') AND bs.`sales_available`>=1
GROUP BY bc.`package_id`
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to assume your table structure (in a minimal way). Is this correct?

[image: Relationships between tables]

If my assumption is right, "INNER-ing" JOIN tables should solve your problems? Isn't it?

```
SELECT bs.`sales_available` sale_to
    ,hp.`package_name`
FROM `tbl_booking_categories` bc
INNER JOIN `tbl_booking_suite` bs ON bc.`id` = bs.`booking_cat_id`
INNER JOIN `tbl_holiday_packages` hp ON hp.`id` = bc.`package_id`
INNER JOIN `tbl_room_type` rt ON rt.`id` = bc.`room_type_id`
WHERE bc.`room_type_id` = '5'
    AND bs.booked_date BETWEEN '2017-08-10' AND '2017-08-11'
    AND bs.`sales_available` >= 1
GROUP BY bc.`package_id`
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts... I got it sorted out by counting booked dates and further comparing.


SELECT COUNT(bs.`booked_date`) AS datewisecount,rt.`display_name`,
rt.total_rooms 
FROM `tbl_booking_categories` bc 
LEFT JOIN `tbl_booking_suite` bs ON bc.`id`=bs.`booking_cat_id` 
LEFT JOIN `tbl_holiday_packages` hp ON hp.`id`=bc.`package_id` 
LEFT JOIN `tbl_room_type` rt ON rt.`id`=bc.`room_type_id` 
WHERE bc.`room_type_id`='5' AND bs.booked_date>='2017-08-20' AND bs.booked_date<'2017-08-26' AND bs.`sales_available`>='1' 
GROUP BY bc.`package_id`